# Парсинг сайта t.myscore.ru

Tags: парсер

Вот так выглядит главная страница сайта t.myscore.ru:
[image: t.myscore.ru]

А при попытке просмотреть исходный код страницы в браузере происходят чудеса, таблица с чемпионатами отсутствует. Вопрос, как прочесть эти данные?

Comment: Только что проверил. Хром показывает таблицу в исходном коде. Смотрю через Ctrl+Shift+I.

Comment: Тут таблица автоматически генерируется с помощью JavaScript, поэтому в исходном коде видно только сам скрипт, а в прогруженной странице, с помощью интструментов разработчика, видно таблицу. Подождите несколько минут, возможно смогу что-нибудь подсказать

Comment: А по Ctrl+U не показывает. Как ее правильно парсить?

Comment: Как всегда просто стырить не получилось :) ищите урл в яваскрипте откуда он берет данные, оттуда по аналогии и берите сами.